# Question about inner product of $C_{2}[a,b]$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

My question, I think, is quite simple.
I have a space $C_{2}[a,b]$ of complex-valued continuous functions. I checked that functional $$(f,g) = \int_{a}^{b} f(t)\overline{g}(t)dt$$ is a inner product on this space.
But I don't know how should I work with them. 
For example, I have a function $g(t) = t^3$ hence $g(t) = (x+iy)^3$ and $\overline{g}(t) = (x-iy)^3$?
I should consider any function $u(x,y)$ as sum: $u(x,y) = f(x,y) + ih(x,y)$? 
Thank you very much and sorry for pretty elementary question..

Comment: For $g:t\mapsto t^3$ for example, you would have :

$||g||^2=(g,g)=\int_{a}^{b}t^3\bar{t}^3dt=\int_{a}^{b}t^6dt=\frac{1}{7}(b^7-a^7). $

The variable lies in $[a;b]$. It's the *images* that can be complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb C$ is of the form $f(t)=f_1(t)+if_2(t)$ where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are real valued functions.

In particular, for $g(t)=t^3$, this is just a real valued function.